# Pass parameters to method in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have several buttons, each which calls its own function onClick. These buttons indicate to a ScrollView to scroll to a particular element (like links in a Table of Contents). I have three methods, each with almost identical code; Obviously, it would be better to pass the View to scroll to in the method.

info_page.xml:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:onClick="scrollToSetup"
    ... />

<TextView
    ...
    android:onClick="scrollToObjective"
    .../>

<TextView
    ...
    android:onClick="scrollToGameplay"
    .../>
```

InfoPageActivity.java:

```
...
public void scrollToSetup(View v) {
    View setupHeader = findViewById(R.id.header_setup);
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, setupHeader.getTop());
}

public void scrollToObjective(View v) {
    View setupHeader = findViewById(R.id.header_objective);
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, setupHeader.getTop());
}

public void scrollToGameplay(View v) {
    View setupHeader = findViewById(R.id.header_gameplay);
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, setupHeader.getTop());
}
...
```

I'm not quite sure how this would work exactly, but hopefully something like:

info_page.xml:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:onClick"scrollTo","header_setup"
    ... />

<TextView
    ...
    android:onClick"scrollTo","header_objective"
    ... />
<TextView
    ...
    android:onClick"scrollTo","header_gameplay"
    ... />
```

and InfoPageActivity.java:

```
...
public void scrollToGameplay(View v, View target) {
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, target.getTop());
}
...
```

Does anyone have any way to do this, or pointers to docs I can read for this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using `DataBinding`. Then passing a custom `Listener` to the `Binding` and if for example, you want to scroll to view with id (in the same XML) `R.id.my_target_view1` your xml `onClick` method should look something like this:

`android:onClick='@{(v) -> listener.scrollToGameplay(v, myTargetView1)}'`

Because when generating the `Binding`, the generator converts `snake_case` to `camelCase`.

**Note:** My proposal could be overkill but I don't think there is another way achieving this.